# Filter object array based on nested array filter criteria and return new map props along with filter result nested object

Tags: javascript, array-filter

How to get filter nested data and result map to new props name. Please have look at below codesandbox.

https://codesandbox.io/s/es6-filter-sub-data-and-return-new-obj-d9s0o1?file=/src/index.js

Have tried with below approach but its not getting filter for child objects.

```
console.log(getFilterData("type2"));        
function getFilterData(type) {

  var r = data.filter((d) => d.subs.some((s) => s.type === type));
  console.log(r);
  /* expected to return: (only return "type2" filter result with 
  some new map "prop key" name)
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "name_1",
    subModule: [ {
      id: "sub_2",
      type: "type2"
    },
    {
      id: "sub_3",
      type: "type2"
    }]
  }
  */
}

var data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "name_1",
    subs: [
      {
        id: "sub_1",
        name: "sub_1",
        type: "type1"
      },
      {
        id: "sub_2",
        name: "sub_2",
        type: "type2"
      },
      {
        id: "sub_3",
        name: "sub_3",
        type: "type2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "name_2",
    subs: [
      {
        id: "sub_11",
        name: "sub_11",
        type: "type3"
      },
      {
        id: "sub_21",
        name: "sub_21",
        type: "type1"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) your `data` to a new array which has objects with the `subs` array filtered on `type`, then [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) that array by the length of the `subs` array:

```js
var data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "name_1",
    subs: [
      { id: "sub_1", name: "sub_1", type: "type1" },
      { id: "sub_2", name: "sub_2", type: "type2" },
      { id: "sub_3", name: "sub_3", type: "type2" }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "name_2",
    subs: [
      { id: "sub_11", name: "sub_11", type: "type3" },
      { id: "sub_21", name: "sub_21", type: "type1" }
    ]
  }
];

const getFilterData = (data, type) =>
  data
    .map(o => ({...o, subs : o.subs.filter(s => s.type == type) }))
    .filter(o => o.subs.length)
    
console.log(getFilterData(data, 'type2'))
```

If you want to change the name of the `subs` array in the process, change the `map` and `filter` to:

```js
.map(({subs, ...rest}) => ({...rest, subModule : subs.filter(s => s.type == type) }))
.filter(o => o.subModule.length)
```

Also, if you want to remove the name field from subs, change

```
subs.filter(s => s.type == type)
```

to

```
subs.filter(s => s.type == type).map(({name, ...rest}) => ({...rest}))
```

Updated code with both changes:

```js
var data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "name_1",
    subs: [
      { id: "sub_1", name: "sub_1", type: "type1" },
      { id: "sub_2", name: "sub_2", type: "type2" },
      { id: "sub_3", name: "sub_3", type: "type2" }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "name_2",
    subs: [
      { id: "sub_11", name: "sub_11", type: "type3" },
      { id: "sub_21", name: "sub_21", type: "type1" }
    ]
  }
];

const getFilterData = (data, type) =>
  data
    .map(({subs, ...rest}) => ({
      ...rest, 
      subModule : subs.filter(s => s.type == type).map(({name, ...rest}) => ({...rest}))
    }))
    .filter(o => o.subModule.length)    
console.log(getFilterData(data, 'type2'))
```

Comment: Thanks for result.  Can you please guide 1) how `subs.length` is able to give only filter result and 2) how to map the result set like, "subs" to "subModule" and only return "id" , "type" field and skip "name" field.

Comment: @user3711357 because when you filter out all the non-type2 values, the subs array for id 2 will have no entries; hence it's length will be 0, which is considered false by `filter`, hence that object is removed from the result

Comment: @user3711357 if you want to remove the `name` field from `subs`, change `subs.filter(s => s.type == type)` to `subs.filter(s => s.type == type).map(({name, ...rest}) => ({...rest}))`

Comment: @user3711357 I've added another snippet to the answer which incorporates both those changes

Comment: oh ok. Thanks, make sense now, As its getting length 0 because of filtered data. And then just filter by length exists.

Answer (score 1):

If you can mutate the `data`:

```js
data.filter(item => { 
   item.subs = item.subs.filter(s => s.type === 'type2')
   return item.subs.length
})
```